# How can i create an animation like this in css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create an animated text like bellow using css, how can i do this?

[image]

I already tried this:

```css
span1 {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e74c3c;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation: move 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    top: -50px;
  }
  40% {
    top: -100px;
  }
  60% {
    top: -150px;
  }
  80% {
    top: -200px;
  }
  100% {
    top: -300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<span1>
  web developer<br /> css cowboy<br /> self-facilitating media node<br /> box inside a box<br /> part of the problem
</span1>
```

but it has a delay after last text that i need to remove!

Comment: @ehsan no problem! i need the style!

Comment: What have you tried so far coding wise?

Comment: could you share enough code tat shows your issue and what you tried so far ? It can be done in HTML/CSS indeed, but what do you have ?

Comment: @GCyrillus I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See This:**

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

div {
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;

}

div p {
  height: 100px;
  animation: move  7s infinite linear;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -100px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 0;
}

@keyframes move {
0% {bottom: -100px;}
10%, 20% {bottom: 0px}
40%,50% {bottom: 100px;}
70%,80% {bottom: 200px;}
100% {bottom: 300px}
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>50% OFF</p>
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <p>Write by: Ehsan Taghdisi</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's cool.tnx, what should i change if i want to make it three item?

Comment: nothings changed! can you please update your answer with three <p> tag.

Comment: if you want for dynamic elements,you must use of javascript.

Comment: what if its just for 3 items not different elements , i'm not so good in css and i just wanna do it the fast way possible.

Comment: thanx, your awsome!

Comment: Thanks buddy, you definitely saved my day! :*

Answer (score 0):

```css
.anim1 {
  animation: anim1 1.5s infinite;
}

.anim2 {
  animation: anim2 1.5s infinite;
}

@keyframes anim1 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-80px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
}

@keyframes anim2 {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(-80px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="height:40px;overflow:hidden">

  <h1 class="anim1">Hello animation 1</h1>
  <h1 class="anim2">Hello animation 2</h1>
```

Comment: @MahboobehMohammadi It just demonstrate basic animation as you've not mentioned specific issue or any other try out.

Comment: i added a gif, and also i add some code. i tried this animation you made before, but i want the texts to go up and start over again from the first text. like see Hello animation 1 goes up then a delay then Hello animation 2 will be shown like before and the it repeats from begining.

Comment: @MahboobehMohammadi Did you mean you want just some delay while text is shown and then move fast to up/down?

Comment: i want to show first text, then movie it up and show the second then move the second up and show first and go on like this.